# How to get the value of a gridview header when it gets clicked - vb.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net

I have a grid-view that allows sorting by column, when the column is clicked.

I would like to learn if there is a way to obtain the value of the header that is clicked, and then pass it trough the query-string.

This is one of the columns in the grid-view:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Order ID" SortExpression="orderId">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:HyperLink ID="lblOrderID" runat="Server"></asp:HyperLink>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left"></ItemStyle>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Using this header example, when the user clicks the Order Id header, I would like to retrieve in code, the value of the clicked header, in this case Order Id. Then store that value in a variable so that I can use it later in the code.

I have been looking for information on how to obtain the value of a grid-view header on a click event, but I have not found any information that would help me figure out how to do it, other than by using JavaScript like 
[in this question][1]

But that answer retrieves all header values, and I just need the one that gets clicked for sorting.

And this are some of the grid-view properties:

```
<asp:GridView EnableViewState="false" ID="gdvHeaders" runat="Server"
        AutoGenerateColumns="false" Visible="false" CssClass="tableWhole"
        RowStyle-CssClass="tableRow" AlternatingRowStyle-CssClass="tableAlt"
        AllowSorting="true" HeaderStyle-CssClass="tableHeader">
```

What I tried so far, in the RwoDataBound code:

```
If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.Header Then
    For Each cell As DataControlFieldCell In e.Row.Cells
            cell.Attributes.Add("onclick", "javascript:GetHeaderText('" +  cell.Text + "')")
    Next
End If
```

Then using JavaScript:

```
function GetHeaderText(txt) {
    alert(txt);
};
```

But I do not get the alert when I click any header. And this is the HTML source:

```
<table class="tableWhole" cellspacing="0" rules="all" UseAccessibleHeaderText="true" border="1" id="ctl00_content_OrderHistory_gdvHeaders" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
<tr class="tableHeader" onclick="JavaScript:GetHeaderText(&#39;ctl00_content_OrderHistory_gdvHeaders&#39;">
    <th scope="col">&nbsp;</th><th scope="col"><a href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$content$OrderHistory$gdvHeaders&#39;,&#39;Sort$Customer.email&#39;)">E-Mail</a></th>
    <th scope="col"><a href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$content$OrderHistory$gdvHeaders&#39;,&#39;Sort$orderId&#39;)">Order ID</a></th>
    <th scope="col"><a href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$content$OrderHistory$gdvHeaders&#39;,&#39;Sort$Soldaddress.First&#39;)">First</a></th>
    <th scope="col"><a href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$content$OrderHistory$gdvHeaders&#39;,&#39;Sort$Soldaddress.Last&#39;)">Last</a></th>
    <th scope="col"><a href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$content$OrderHistory$gdvHeaders&#39;,&#39;Sort$created&#39;)">Created</a></th>
    <th scope="col"><a href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$content$OrderHistory$gdvHeaders&#39;,&#39;Sort$Tax&#39;)">Tax</a></th>
    <th scope="col"><a href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$content$OrderHistory$gdvHeaders&#39;,&#39;Sort$Freight&#39;)">Freight</a></th>
    <th scope="col"><a href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$content$OrderHistory$gdvHeaders&#39;,&#39;Sort$total&#39;)">Total</a></th>
    <th scope="col"><a href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$content$OrderHistory$gdvHeaders&#39;,&#39;Sort$CRMOrderID&#39;)">AX Order No.</a></th>
    <th scope="col"><a href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$content$OrderHistory$gdvHeaders&#39;,&#39;Sort$CRMStatus&#39;)">Processed</a></th>
</tr>
```

Many thanks for your help.

**UPDATE**

I was able to figure out how to get the sort by which column value, by using the SortExpression within the sorting event:

```
strSortValue = e.SortExpression.ToString
```

Then I build my URL in the following fashion:

```
Page.ResolveUrl("~/order-review.aspx?order_id=" & e.Row.DataItem.OrderID _
                                & "&siteKey=" & spiderSiteKey _
                                & "&strEnv=" & spiderStrEnv _
                                & "&Start=" & Me.startDate.Text _
                                & "&End=" & Me.endDate.Text _
                                & "&SortBy=" & strSortValue)  << here is the sort by column clicked.
```

Many thanks for viewing this post.

Comment: This is not clear and too broad. What have you tried, what was it where you've got stuck? What means _"value of the header"_ at all?

Comment: I updated my question with more details, and then I updated it again with my solution. Thank you.